# How can I install kernel 4.19.1 in Ubuntu 18.10?

Tags: kernel

The latest kernel that I can find in the repository is 4.19.0. How can I install 4.19.1 in Ubuntu 18.10?

```
user@user:~$ sudo apt install linux-image-
linux-image-4.15.0-1021-oem                  linux-image-gke
linux-image-4.15.0-1024-oem                  linux-image-kvm
linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic                linux-image-lowlatency
linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic                linux-image-oem
linux-image-4.18.0-1002-aws                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-1021-oem
linux-image-4.18.0-1002-gcp                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-1024-oem
linux-image-4.18.0-1003-azure                linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-1002-gcp
linux-image-4.18.0-1003-kvm                  linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-1003-azure
linux-image-4.18.0-10-generic                linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-10-generic
linux-image-4.18.0-10-lowlatency             linux-image-unsigned-4.18.0-10-lowlatency
linux-image-aws                              linux-image-unsigned-4.18.13-041813-generic
linux-image-azure                            linux-image-unsigned-4.18.14-041814-generic
linux-image-azure-edge                       linux-image-unsigned-4.18.15-041815-generic
linux-image-extra-virtual                    linux-image-unsigned-4.18.16-041816-generic
linux-image-gcp                              linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900-generic
```

Comment: Note: The mainline kernels do not include any Ubuntu-provided drivers or patches. They are not supported and are not appropriate for production use.

Comment: More helpful link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: Are you interested in becoming a kernel tester, locating problems and filing bugs? Or is this for daily-driver or production use where you want reliability?

Comment: 4.19.1 is a stable kernel.

Comment: Hmm... isn't it the case that Ubuntu doesn't increment the third number? I feel like the stock Ubuntu kernel is always `x.x.0-x-generic`. The first and second `x` don't change within an Ubuntu version, but the third `x` is incremented, eg `4.15.0-36`, `4.15.0-38` (latest two on 18.04)

Comment: I believe zanna is correct. And so is Mark J Adams you can wget the files and dpkg it